Map Lambda, Named Function with Multiple Row Result
I tried to use lambda to reiterate a query function with a combination of condition.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8pUQa90okQMhaJV3Yx-0jBN5qeeJou9T5zYJZPcBXs/edit?usp=sharing
Data



District
Location
Area
Zone




TWH
A
TR
YH


WE
DFSK
REIO
FJL


ASL
RO
DER
OP


CVN
ROI
EWQ
MNB


TWH
WTR
H
WW


JJJ
RO
KLR
OLI


TYR
G4E
UNH
ETR


XTR
HJE
NE
EW



I need to extract the row where the District column matches each row of the following table.
Combination of District   ---(A)









TWH
ASL


CVN
JJJ


TYR
ASL



Anticipated Result











TWH
A
TR
YH


ASL
RO
DER
OP


TWH
WTR
H
WW


CVN
ROI
EWQ
MNB


JJJ
RO
KLR
OLI


ASL
RO
DER
OP


TYR
G4E
UNH
ETR



Please follow the color for a better understanding of the extraction logic.
enter image description here
In the spreadsheet, I use a named function "FUNCTION1" to do the extraction, where query is used with OR condition.  "FUNCTION2" is also added for comparison, where query is used with AND condition.
Making use of vstack and assigning the variable manually, I can produce my anticipated result as follows:
=vstack(FUNCTION1(C14,D14),FUNCTION1(C15,D15),FUNCTION1(C16,D16))

Actually, Table (A) above is a long list.  I tried map and lambda and returned error "Result should be a single row."  The result is found in cell B25.
=map(C14:C16,D14:D16,LAMBDA(valA,valB,FUNCTION1(valA,valB)))

I understand what it means but I don't know how to work around.  Would you please help?  Thanks.

Any backend reason to call it a Combination since within the named function you seem to use an OR Col1='"&districtcondition1&"' or Col1='"&districtcondition2&"'". As of now its just going to be TWH or ASL or CVB or JJJ irrespective of having this combinations thing?

Sorry, typo is revised, thanks

What is the significance of a combination district here? I mean you are pulling & stacking all the available results of TWH; then all the results for ASL; then for CVN and so on.... Does a combination factor even matter?!

yes rockin, the combination matters.  the above data is a replicate of my original data, however, the original data is sensitive and more complex.  so i created the sample above to illustrate the difficulties i encountered.

your query within named function says query(..."where Col1='condition1' OR Col1='condition2') Its essentially saying to look for either (TWH or ASL) OR (CVN or JJJ).  If it would've been something like Col1='condition1' AND Col2='condition2', then definitely combination matters but not in this given scenario!

thanks rockin, rows with TWH and ASL are the rows i need in "Data".  However, using query with AND condition, i would not be able to retrieve both TWH and ASL from data at the same time, so i use query OR condition to retrieve the rows, let me know if further clarification is needed, thanks in advance

To make it simple, Can you add a scenario to your above sample data where the combination_district would fail?!

Hi rockin, I have updated the question, hope you will understand better, thanks.

For FUNCTION1 try: =let(Σ,C14:D16,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(Σ)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Λ,chooserows(Σ,c),FUNCTION1(+Λ,choosecols(Λ,2))))))) and for FUNCTION2 try: =reduce(tocol(,1),C14:D16,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,FUNCTION2(c,c))))
